# How to send video file to firebase storage in ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am working on a Video sharing iOS app and using `Firebase5` as backend. It allow User can choose video and send it to storage. When  I tried the video cannot push to `database` server. Below is my code:

```
static func uploadVideoToFirebaseStorage(videoUrl: URL, onSuccess: @escaping (_ videoUrl: String) -> Void) {
    let videoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
    //Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REF is var STORAGE_ROOT_REF = "gs://****-cdc3c.appspot.com"
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REF).child("posts").child(videoIdString)
    storageRef.putFile(from: videoUrl, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
    storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
        if let error = error {
            return
        }else {
            let videoUrl = url!.absoluteString
            onSuccess(videoUrl)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call this function to upload the video to firebase storage

```
func uploadTOFireBaseVideo(url: URL,
                                  success : @escaping (String) -> Void,
                                  failure : @escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    let name = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).mp4"
    let path = NSTemporaryDirectory() + name

    let dispatchgroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchgroup.enter()

    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let outputurl = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)
    var ur = outputurl
    self.convertVideo(toMPEG4FormatForVideo: url as URL, outputURL: outputurl) { (session) in

        ur = session.outputURL!
        dispatchgroup.leave()

    }
    dispatchgroup.wait()

    let data = NSData(contentsOf: ur as URL)

    do {

        try data?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)

    } catch {

        print(error)
    }

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child(name)
    if let uploadData = data as Data? {
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil
            , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    failure(error)
                }else{
                    let strPic:String = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
                    success(strPic)
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Following function converts the video to mp4 format so that it can be viewed on any device either it be iOS or android

```
func convertVideo(toMPEG4FormatForVideo inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession) -> Void) {
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL as URL)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL as URL, options: nil)

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        handler(exportSession)
    })
}
```

Comment: I believe it's better to have UUID as the video name rather than the time interval because you have a realisable risk of having two video files with the same name if you use time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Call this function to upload video the firebase storage. Its working for me incase any confusion you can ask

```
 static func upload(file: URL, completion: @escaping UploadCompletion) {
    let name = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).mp4"
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
        
        let storageRef = 
    Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child(name)
        if let uploadData = data as Data? {
            let metaData = StorageMetadata()
            metaData.contentType = "video/mp4"
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metaData
                               , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                                if let error = error {
                                    completion(nil, error.localizedDescription)
                                }else{
                                    storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                                        guard let downloadURL = url else {
                                            completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                                            return
                                        }
                                        completion(downloadURL, nil)
                                    }
                                }
                               })
        }
    }catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```