# How to upload video in firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

```
extension UploadVideoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL
        let localFile = videoURL! as URL   // File located on disk
        
        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let riversRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/rivers.mov")

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        let uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                return
            }
            
            let size = metadata.size
            print("Size is ",size)
            riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in {
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    print(url?.absoluteString)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
            
        videoImage.image = info [ .editedImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**AdminApp[3887:89090] Task <637BD2E3-BF23-4E57-8820-7A0953A295CB>.<1> finished with error [-1] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ramishapplocation.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.mov?uploadType=resumable&name=images%2Frivers.mov&upload_id=ABg5-UzzpD6qHs3m5u4fEGOwojHohnDd59e3gIDlGlo-wQVfNqqqzzYIE34ntJuEH-wTT2hgseD9mY8vk3B2Paiy8A&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ramishapplocation.appspot.com/o/images%2Frivers.mov?uploadType=resumable&name=images%2Frivers.mov&upload_id=ABg5-UzzpD6qHs3m5u4fEGOwojHohnDd59e3gIDlGlo-wQVfNqqqzzYIE34ntJuEH-wTT2hgseD9mY8vk3B2Paiy8A&upload_protocol=resumable, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"BackgroundUploadTask <637BD2E3-BF23-4E57-8820-7A0953A295CB>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <637BD2E3-BF23-4E57-8820-7A0953A295CB>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}
**

Comment: That's probably because you are setting metaData to nil.

Comment: So what can I give in metadata

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send video file to firebase storage in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222949/how-to-send-video-file-to-firebase-storage-in-ios)

Comment: @ElTomato Passing nil for the metadata parameter is legit. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file)

Comment: What is this `videoImage.image = info [ .editedImage] as? UIImage` as it will execute before the file is uploaded. You're also guaranteeing that videoURL is valid `let localFile = videoURL! as URL` which if it's not, will throw the error you're getting. Did you add a breakpoint and step through your code line, examining your vars along the way to see what line is crashing? If not, you need to do that and update your question with that info. Troubleshooting your code before posting a question is best practice here on SO.

Comment: Oh and this `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` will close the view before the file is uploaded as well, could lead to a crash. Firebase functions are asynchronous so any code following a firebase function will execute *before* the code within the closure.