# How to store videos in Firebase using Swift

Tags: firebase, video, swiftui, storage

I currently have a function that allows me to upload an image to Firebase Storage. But how in the world can I achieve the same, with a video instead of an image?

I suspect I have to change **UIImage** and **.jpg** to something else. But what is the type of a video?

```
@State var pickedImages: [UIImage] = []
@State var retrievedImages = [UIImage]()
```

**This is my function:**

```
 func uploadImage() {
        // Create storage reference
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        // Turn our image into data
        let selectedImage = pickedImages[0]
        let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        
        guard imageData != nil else {
            let er = "THIS: Error while converting to data"
            return print(er)
        }
        
        // Specifie filepath and name
        let path = "images/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
        let fileRef = storageRef.child(path)
        
        // Upload that data
        let uploadTask = fileRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) {metaData, error in
            print("THIS: from uploadTAsk")
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil && metaData != nil {

                // Save reference in firestore DB
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                
                db.collection("images").document("user1").setData(["url": path]) { error in
                    
                    print("THIS: inside closure")
                    // If there was no errors, display the image
                    if error == nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.retrievedImages.append(selectedImage)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send video file to firebase storage in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222949/how-to-send-video-file-to-firebase-storage-in-ios)

Comment: Not entirely. Or I dont fully understand the code. I use a state to store the picked image, and for that i use `UIImage`, but the answer doesnt really cover what i should use for a video. Any ideas?

Comment: See [Upload files with Cloud Storage on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)

Comment: Well this isnt for swift @RonnieRoyston

Comment: Right, See [Upload files with Cloud Storage on Apple platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files)

Comment: I have looked through it a couple of times already. I dont see anything regarding videos, only images. Am I missing something?

Comment: Video and image files aren't meaningfully different in this context -- don't get hung up on the type.

Comment: I cant get it to work, because i need to know what type videos are. Like Images are `UIImage`. Do you happen to know this? @jnpdx

Comment: You don't need to have the type to upload the file -- all you need is the path. Is the question really how to select the videos to upload?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it - and the code in your question may upload an image *from memory* but has nothing to do with uploading a file from disk. Go here [Uploading From A Local File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) and you'll see UIImage is not involved in that process. You can upload *any* type of file if you go by that guide. Get the local file `let localFile = URL(string: "path/to/image")!` and then upload it `let uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(from: localFile`

Comment: Agree, I might be overcomplicating it. But how do I get the `localFile`? Thats the part of the Docs I dont understand. I use my custom picker to choose the image / video, then what? How do I get the `localFile`? @Jay

Comment: How do you get the local file? Look at the placeholder in the code `let localFile = URL(string: "path/to/image")!`  **path/to/image** is well, the path on disk to the image. You can use the Filemanager to access files on your drive - but that has nothing to do with Firebase or uploading as that's an OS function. If the file is in the documents folder for example, it would be `let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory...` and then add the filename as a pathComponent. I suggest doing some research on handling files in iOS/macOS as that will answer your question.